# Select records that belong to all specified categories

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

A video can have several categories. I want to select a video that belongs to two categories.

The result returned by this query and that the videos belong to only one of the categories in the condition

```sql
SELECT Videos.id, Videos.title
FROM videos Videos 
INNER JOIN categories_videos CategoriesVideos
    ON Videos.id = CategoriesVideos.video_id 
INNER JOIN categories Categories
    ON Categories.id = CategoriesVideos.category_id AND Categories.id IN (21, 35)
LIMIT 25;
```

I tried to do several joins on the categories table but it doesn't change anything.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your `CategoriesVideos.category_id` is 12 for example, you're saying that it has to be `Categories.id = 12 AND (21 OR 35)`, try making it; `ON Categories.id IN (CategoriesVideos.category_id, 21, 35)` and that would make it `Categories.id = (12 OR 21 OR 35)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following approach (could be expanded to test *n* categories):

```
SELECT *
FROM videos
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT video_id
    FROM categories_videos
    WHERE category_id IN (21, 35)
    GROUP BY video_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
```

Answer (score -1):

When you write your join like this

```
AND Categories.id IN(21, 35)
```

you're asking for all videos that has at least one of these Categories.id associated with.

If want only the one who has both, you can try this

```
SELECT Videos.id, Videos.title FROM videos Videos 
INNER JOIN categories_videos CategoriesVideos 
    ON Videos.id = CategoriesVideos.video_id 
INNER JOIN categories Categories 
    ON Categories.id = CategoriesVideos.category_id
AND Categories.id = 21 AND Categories.id =35
LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: The `AND`s in the join would need to be `OR`s, a field can't be `X AND Y AND Z` at the same time

Comment: I have already tried this query, the result is empty.